# AWS Deploy Serverless limit?

Tags: aws-serverless

I have a serverless project, that has quite a few API endpoints, and when I try to deploy all at once I get this error:

Error: The CloudFormation template is invalid: Template format error: Number of resources, 293, is greater than the maximum allowed, 200
at C:...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\serverless\lib\plugins\aws\deplow\lib\validateTemplate.js:20:13

My serverless.yaml functions def looks like this

```
functions:
# Auth: Sign-in
signIn:
    handler: src/collections/auth/auth.signIn
    events:
        - http:
        path: auth/signIn
        method: post
        cors: true

# Admin-User: Find Permission By Role
findPermissionByRole:
    handler: src/collections/permissions/permissions.findPermissionByRole
    events: 
        - http:
        path: permissions/findPermissionByRole
        method: get
        cors: true

# Lookup: FindAll
lookup:
    handler: src/collections/lookup/lookup.find
    events:
        - http:
        path: lookup/find
        method: post
        cors: true

...(1180 lines of code 131 resources)
```

There are 131 Handler/events - but if I try to deploy more than 20 (twenty) I get that error.
So I am confused by the error message specifying 293, and 200 max when I have 131.

Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue to due to the following [limit](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cloudformation-limits.html) in the Cloudformation API:

[image: CloudFormation Limits]

Keep in the mind, serverless can add [up to 6 resources](https://www.serverless.com/blog/serverless-workaround-cloudformation-200-resource-limit/#background-on-the-200-resource-limit) to the CloudFormation request

> For each http event you configured, you end up creating six (!)
>   CloudFormation resources, in addition to shared resources like
>   AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi and AWS::IAM::Role.

To work around this, serverless suggests [one of the following](https://www.serverless.com/blog/serverless-workaround-cloudformation-200-resource-limit/):

- **Break your API down**: opt for a small deployments and small code (split by business domain). But this may require a lot for existing projects.
- **Handle routing in your application logic**: Make some of the heavy lifting done by API Gateway be done by the lambda function instead.
- **Use plugins to split your service into multiple stacks or [nested stacks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-stack.html)**: Use this neat AWS solution for the 200 resource limit in one cloudformation template. (e.g. [serverless-plugin-split-stacks](https://github.com/dougmoscrop/serverless-plugin-split-stacks), [serverless-plugin-additional-stacks](https://github.com/nordcloud/serverless-plugin-additional-stacks) ... etc)
- **Ask AWS for the CloudFormation limit increase**: Won't solve the root cause and only solve it til your app gets bigger and run into the same issue but a higher limit and more complex/bigger code.